# Phpunit using zend framework 3 and doctrine, Mocking not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit, zend-test

I'm using zend-test in zf3, using doctrine, when I run the test for PostController showAction(),it is showing following error

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite Post --stderr
PHPUnit 7.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F      1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 169 ms, Memory: 16.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) PostTest\Controller\PostControllerTest::testIfPostDetailsShownSuccessfully
Failed asserting response code "200", actual status code is "500"

Exceptions raised:
Exception 'TypeError' with message 'Return value of Post\Entity\Post::getUser() must be an instance of User\Entity\User, null returned' in /var/www/html/crud/module/Post/src/Entity/Post.php:122

/var/www/html/crud/vendor/zendframework/zend-test/src/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:451
/var/www/html/crud/module/Post/test/Controller/PostControllerTest.php:95
```

**PostController showAction()**

```
public function showAction()
{
    $postId = $this->params()->fromRoute('postId');
    $post = $this->postService->getPost($postId);

    return new ViewModel([
        'post' => $post
    ]);
}
```

**Post Service getPost()**

```
public function getPost($postId = null)
{
    $post = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Post::class)->find($postId);

    return $post;
}
```

**PostControllerTest testIfPostDetailsShownSuccessfully()**

```
public function testIfPostDetailsShownSuccessfully()
{

            $mockedEm = $this->createMock(EntityManager::class);

            $postRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(PostRepository::class);
            $postRepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('find')
                ->willReturn($this->getPostMock());

            $postRepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('findOneBy')
                ->willReturn($this->getPostMock());

            $userRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);
            $userRepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('find')
                ->willReturn(new User());

            $userRepositoryMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('findOneBy')
                ->willReturn(new User());

            $userEntityMock = $this->createMock(UserRepository::class);
            $userEntityMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('find')
                ->willReturn(new User());

            $this->dispatch('/post/1');
            $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
  }

/**
 * @return MockObject
 */
public function getPostMock()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setEmail('a@a.in');

    $postMock = $this->createMock(Post::class);
    $postMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getUser')
        ->willReturn($user);

    return $postMock;
}
```

A post always has one user, I have getUser() method in Post entity which returns User entity object. But I'm unable to mock post object and it always recieving getUser as null.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder nobody is active here regarding zend framework, doctrine and phpunit !!!